# cocos2d: alloc ccsprite memory 4MB, adding as child to scenes mem=11MB

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, addchild, ccsprite

i have started with helloworld template.
added some menu and started performance tool->allocation.
result: 1.9MB
ok, so the empty scene is 2MB
now added instance variable ccsprite initialized with an image 1024x1024

```
CCsprite *test=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"img1024x1024.png];
```

and started performance tool->allocation.
result: 6MB
ok, the image in memory is 4MB, +2MB of the empty
now added to the schen with

```
[self addChild:test];
```

performance tool->allocation.
result: 11MB
is that normal?
every sprite i'll add as child will double my memory usage?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding one sprite and thinking that each sprite will add the same amount of memory allocated is not really logical. Consider the following:

1. You may be using a same texture over
   and over again which wouldn't
   increase memory much at all.
2. Loading several 1024x1024 sprites is
   not normal behavior at all.
3. The image you are loading may not be
   compressed much.
4. Depending on the application you are
   making that memory usage may not be
   an issue.

If you are really worried about memory usage, I would add the appropriate amount of sprites scaled down the the appropriate size that your application is going to use and add them and check Instruments again.

Comment: perhaps i axplayned not well.

Comment: perhaps i explayned not well. i'm makeing a test: only one sprite, like a background, i have choosen a large image this amount of memory really visible. when i allocate the ccsprite *test the amount of memory from allocation-tool is what i expect: 4MB for an uncompressed png. that's ok. what i'm not expecting is that if i add as child to the scene, WHY the amount of memory increase so much?

Comment: I understood well enough I think. But your test is not a real world example and you would be better off with what  suggested to get valid results.

Comment: i have found that there are 2 malloc made by cocos2d, here is the link to the stack tree: [link](http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/6810/immaginetl.png)

Comment: They look like they are coming from very different areas, I would still suggest to try a couple images the size of what you will be using and investigating it.

Comment: I'm having the exact same pb. See http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/texture-uses-twice-more-memory-than-expected-please-help/15206 for details. Did you found the reason ? BTW, I've got exactly the same in my real app with 220MB of textures, so that's not a matter of testing a sample vs testing in a real environment.